# How to detect parent scroll event out of iframe => get iframe-position-fixed-polyfill work

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, css-position

First a short introduction to understand my problem.

My company uses a restricted community system for the intranet, which does not allow the use of javascript in pages. You can only place code through an internal editor and javascript will be deleted automatically after saving. My workaround is to use the community page as parent page and load my content, located on a sharepoint, through an iframe. This is not elegant but works perfect, no problems and I am able to use javascript. I have asked our IT and got the permission for this.

### What I want to do

I want to add a vertical menu bar, which stays in a fixed position on the left side. Solution one is to code this menu bar in each parent page using html and css. This works fine, but if I have changes on the menu I have to update the code in each parent page. This is time consuming and could be error prone.

More elegant would be to save the menu bar in a seperate file and load this file in each page. While the parent page could not use javascript I have to load it through the iframe page.

iframe call inside parent page:

```
<iframe src="https://sharepoint.abc.com/index.aspx"></iframe>
```

loading the menu through the iframe page "index.aspx":

```
<div id="includedMenuBar"></div>
<script src="demo/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedMenuBar").load("menubar.aspx"); 
    });
</script>
```

This works perfect, but now the used css `position: fixed;` and `top: 100px;` for the menu orientate at the iframe page index.aspx. If I now scroll the parent page the menu bar is fixed to the iframe page but scrolls, because the iframe pages moves throug the scrolling of the parent page.

To solve this I tried [iframe-position-fixed-polyfill](https://github.com/mercedesbenzio/iframe-position-fixed-polyfill) which works perfect but needs the same domain for parent and iframe page. But my parent page loads from the company intranet and my iframe page loads from a sharepoint. So I need a cross-domain-communication.

A solution could be a cross-domain-event-handler like [PostEvent](https://github.com/julianxhokaxhiu/PostEvent). But I could not place any javascript on the parent page.

### Problem

How can I get the [iframe-position-fixed-polyfill](https://github.com/mercedesbenzio/iframe-position-fixed-polyfill) work even if I need a cross-domain-communication and can not place any javascript inside the parent page?

Maybe there is a simpler solution for a fixed menu bar loaded through the iframe page I do not see?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Does nobody has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god. Keep it simple should be the device. My solution which works for me. Load the menubar through another iframe in the parent page. Make this iframe fixed through an enclosed div.

```
<div style="position: fixed; top: 385px">
  <iframe src="menubar.html" style="border: currentColor; border-image: none; overflow: hidden;" width="110" height="300"></iframe>
</div>
```

No scipt language is necessary.